# awk filter columns with calculated values and number range | updated

Tags: awk, numbers, compare, multiple-columns

Hi i dont know how to achieve expected output from given
input file , current code giving output but need to have to expected one

```
input file                     awk code output
--------

3700 TEXT_0A 34 NA NA        | 3700  TEXT_0A  34    NA   NA    850
3721 TEXT_0A 55 ete 851      | 3721  TEXT_0A  55    ete  851   850
3701 TEXT_0A 100 NA NA       | 3701  TEXT_0A  100   NA   NA    850
3724 TEXT_0A 150 ete 1275    | 3724  TEXT_0A  150   ete  1275  1275
3713 TEXT_0A 170 ete 1445    | 3713  TEXT_0A  170   ete  1445  1445
25 TEXT_XA 200 ete 822       | 3686  TEXT_0A  200   ete  822   1700
3686 TEXT_0A 200 ete 822     | 3692  TEXT_0A  200   ete  1700  1700
3692 TEXT_0A 200 ete 1700    | 3716  TEXT_0A  200   ete  3000  1700
3716 TEXT_0A 200 ete 3000    | 3688  TEXT_0A  250   ete  822   1875
88 TEXT_AF 250 ete 822       | 3708  TEXT_0A  300   ete  2250  2250
69 DNTT_AF 250 ete 822       | 3704  TEXT_0A  304   ete  2280  2280
3688 TEXT_0A 250 ete 822     | 3705  TEXT_0A  304   ete  2350  2280
3708 TEXT_0A 300 ete 2250    | 3689  TEXT_0A  400   ete  3000  3000
3704 TEXT_0A 304 ete 2280    | 3717  TEXT_0A  400   ete  3002  3000
3705 TEXT_0A 304 ete 2350    | 3706  TEXT_0A  404   ete  3030  3030
3689 TEXT_0A 400 ete 3000    | 3696  TEXT_0A  500   ete  3750  3750
3717 TEXT_0A 400 ete 3002    | 3707  TEXT_0A  650   ete  4500  4875
3706 TEXT_0A 404 ete 3030    | 3720  TEXT_0A  800   ete  3000  6000
3696 TEXT_0A 500 ete 3750    | 3694  TEXT_0A  1000  ete  7500  7500
3707 TEXT_0A 649.5 ete 4500  | 
3720 TEXT_0A 800 ete 3000    | 
3694 TEXT_0A 1000 ete 7500   |
```

filter rules:

1. filter lines containging strings _0A and exclude lines containing
   DNTT _AF _XA based on column $3 <=100 assign to output column $6
   fixed value 850
2. based on column $3 > 100 && $3 <=200  within this number range
   assign to output column $6 calculated value $3*8.5
3. based on column $3 > 200 && $3 <=1000 within this number range
   assign to output column $6 calculated value $3*7.5
4. and filter it to expected output once compared if not equeal column
   $5 and $6 below

expected output:

```
3700  TEXT_0A  34    NA   NA    850
3721  TEXT_0A  55    ete  851   850
3701  TEXT_0A  100   NA   NA    850
3686  TEXT_0A  200   ete  822   1700
3716  TEXT_0A  200   ete  3000  1700
3688  TEXT_0A  250   ete  822   1875
3705  TEXT_0A  304   ete  2350  2280
3717  TEXT_0A  400   ete  3002  3000
3707  TEXT_0A  650   ete  4500  4875
3720  TEXT_0A  800   ete  3000  6000
```

### partially working code:

```
awk '{if (( $2 ~ /_0A/ && !/DNTT|_AF|_XA/ && $3 <=100 )) \
printf ("%s %s %.0f %s %s %.0f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,850); \
else if (( $2 ~ /_0A/ && !/DNTT|_AF|_XA/ && $3 > 100 && $3 <=200 )) \
printf ("%s %s %.0f %s %s %.0f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$3*8.5); \
else if (( $2 ~ /_0A/ && !/DNTT|_AF|_XA/ && $3 > 200 && $3 <=1000 )) \
printf ("%s %s %.0f %s %s %.0f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$3*7.5)}' file2 | column -t
```

Comment: i dont know how to compare those $10 and $11 colums in last step, or how to do it easily

Comment: Can't you reduce this to one case that will show you how to solve the others? And, can't we solve this with 3-5 columns and 2-5 records of sample data? Search for the [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section in this link, and then the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section in the same link. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, ok i will rewrite question

Comment: Hmm, sorry if you read my previous  comments today, but I now think your question still needs some improvement. (But a plus one for improving your Q). As you have removed the `DNTT|_AF|_XA` from your data, you should remove that from your sample data. As you are trying to filter that data away (anyway), you could think of this as `grep -v 'DNTT|_AF|_XA' file | awk ....`. Do you see, you have eliminated the `DNTT|_AF|_XA` and your logic doesn't have to account for that at all. Going out now for shopping, will check back later. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter hi , thanks for pointing out that one with grep, but for me its crucial problem with  to just show only  non on equal column no. 5+ 6 > aka filter rule 4 which is missing for me to have it completed expected output, enjoy shopping and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the lines from 1 to 4, and converting this to awk:

`gawk '$0~"_0A" && $0!~"DNTT"{ $6=(($3>100 && $3<=200)?($3*8.5):($3>200 && $3<=1000?($3*7.5):850)); if($5!=$6){ print }}'  input.txt`

output:

```
3700 TEXT_0A 34 NA NA 850
3721 TEXT_0A 55 ete 851 850
3701 TEXT_0A 100 NA NA 850
3686 TEXT_0A 200 ete 822 1700
3716 TEXT_0A 200 ete 3000 1700
3688 TEXT_0A 250 ete 822 1875
3705 TEXT_0A 304 ete 2350 2280
3717 TEXT_0A 400 ete 3002 3000
3707 TEXT_0A 649.5 ete 4500 4871.25
3720 TEXT_0A 800 ete 3000 6000
```

An if statement (`if a=b then c else d;`) can also be written as (`a=b?c:d`)

NOTE:  You have to do the exclusion of `_AF _XA`, it was unclear to me, because of no seeing `_XA`. That's why i excluded `DNTT`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
cat calc.awk

$2 ~ /_0A/ && !/DNTT|_AF|_XA/ {
   if ( $3 <=100  )
      n = 850
   else if ( $3 > 100 && $3 <=200 )
      n = $3*8.5
   else if ( $3 > 200 && $3 <=1000 )
      n = $3*7.5
   if ($5 != n)   
      printf ("%s %s %.0f %s %s %.0f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,n)
}
```

Then use it as:

```sh
awk -f calc.awk file | column -t
```

```
3700  TEXT_0A  34   NA   NA    850
3721  TEXT_0A  55   ete  851   850
3701  TEXT_0A  100  NA   NA    850
3686  TEXT_0A  200  ete  822   1700
3716  TEXT_0A  200  ete  3000  1700
3688  TEXT_0A  250  ete  822   1875
3705  TEXT_0A  304  ete  2350  2280
3717  TEXT_0A  400  ete  3002  3000
3707  TEXT_0A  650  ete  4500  4871
3720  TEXT_0A  800  ete  3000  6000
```

Comment: i tried it almost works, but having problem with rounding up in output e.g. if i will add sample line "3717 TEXT_0A 141 ete 3000 1700 1198.5"  i tried instead of { print }   use of printf ("%s %s %s %s %s %0.f n\" $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) but it not rounding, do u have idea where to put there, having same problem with previous solution, printf 0.f will not round number up